# What is the remainder of $6^{17}$ divided by $17^6$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the general method to solve such questions ?

Comment: This is probably not what you're looking for, but the fastest real-world method is to use a PC, which says $20220503$.

Comment: I think, Use logarithms if you have time. take $x={16^7}/{17^6}$, then take log, you will get quotient, then multiply $17^6$ with integer part of $x$, then subtract that value from $16^7$ using logarithms.

Comment: @DanShved : If there is no simple method then yes, this is the best approach ! :)

Comment: @SHREE6174 Can you elaborate on how that works?

Comment: Say, $7/2=3.5$ so multiply 2 with integer part of 3.5 i.e., 3,we get 6. Now subtract 6 from 7 you will get 1. So 1 is remainder.

Comment: @SHREE6174 : You missed the answer by just 20220502 ! :)

Comment: I believe SHREE174 was giving an example of the method, not stating it as an answer to your specific question.

Comment: $log(x)=log({6^17}/{17^6})$,
$log(x)=17log(6)-6log(17)$,
then take antilog, you will get $x$.

Comment: I am getting 20220503.

Comment: $ln(x)=17ln(6)-6ln(17)=13.46063$
=>$x=70125.XXXXX$,
ignore the decimal part, now multiply 70125 with divisor$17^6$, using log and antilog you ll get 20220503.

Comment: @CalvinLin: I think SHREE6174 is describing the usual method of finding the remainder: if $a = bq + r$, then we can find $r$ as $a - bq$, where $q$ is the integer part of $a/b$. The use of logarithms is only to help with the division.

Comment: @SHREE6174 That's the point of Dan's comment, to use a calculator to do the exponentiation calculation. Otherwise, how do you propose to show that $70125 < e^{13.46063} < 70126$?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, Yes.The use of logarithm is only for simplify the power. If he use the calculator or any electronic equipment then no need of all these things, just type the problem in computer.

Comment: @SHREE6174 As a further note, you essentially still need to do the calculation of $6^{17}$ and $17^6$ at the end to calculate the value of $6^{17} - 70125 \times 17^6$. So adding the logarithm calculation introduces unneeded complexity.

Comment: @CalvinLin: I would disagree. (1) Even after calculating $6^{17}=16926659444736$ and $17^6=24137569$, doing the actual division $16926659444736/24137569$ by hand is difficult, and logarithms help immensely here — this after all is the exactly the kind of purpose for which logarithms and log tables were invented. (2) Logarithms can also be used to calculate $6^{17}$ and $17^6$ in the first place. I think you just dislike the approach because you feel that mathematically it is no different from doing everything by hand, but it is IMHO incorrect to say that logarithms are no help here.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's have a go by hand. We note that $6^2=36=2(17+1)$ so that $$6^{17}=6\cdot(6^2)^8=6\cdot 2^8 \cdot(17+1)^8$$

Now we use $2^4=17-1$ to give $$6\cdot(17-1)^2\cdot(17+1)^8=6\cdot(17^2-1)^2\cdot(17+1)^6$$

Let's put $x=17$ and reduce modulo $x^6=17x^5$ as we go (I prefer to keep the powers and $x$ works better for me than $17$).

$(x+1)^6=6x^5+15x^4+20x^3+15x^2+6x+1$

$(x^2-1)^2=x^4-2x^2+1$

So that $(x^2-1)^2(x+1)^6=$ (dropping $x^6$ and higher powers, all equalities now are modulo $17^6$)

$6x^5+x^4-40x^5-30x^4-12x^3-2x^2+6x^5+15x^4+20x^3+15x^2+6x+1 =$

$-28x^5-14x^4+8x^3+13x^2+6x+1 =$

$6x^5-14x^4+8x^3+13x^2+6x+1$

We now need to multiply this by 6 to obtain

$36x^5-84x^4+48x^3+78x^2+36x+6$

and using $x=17$ this becomes

$2x^5-5x^5+x^4+3x^4-3x^3+5x^3-7x^2+2x^2+2x+6$

$=14x^5+4x^4+2x^3-5x^2+2x+6$

The value of this expression with $x=17$ is $20220503$ - see Dan Shved's comment. It doesn't look like there is any much simpler way to do it.

Comment: In case it helps any $20220503=19\cdot 41\cdot 101 \cdot 257$ which doesn't suggest any obvious simplification. The final polynomial has no roots mod $17$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\frac{6^{17}}{17^6}=\left(\frac{6^3}{17}\right)^5*\left(\frac{6^2}{17}\right)=\left(\frac{216}{17}\right)^5*\left(\frac{36}{17}\right)$$
... then modular calculation.

Comment: Please elaborate on the modular calculation.